# Comparing file versions in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to use the following code to compare a file's version to a specified version, and tell me which one is higher.

```
function Get-FileVersionInfo            
{            
  param(            
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]            
     [string]$FileName)            

  if(!(test-path $filename)) {            
  write-host "File not found"            
  return $null            
  }            

  return [System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo]::GetVersionInfo($FileName)            

}

$file = Get-FileVersionInfo("C:\program files\internet explorer\iexplore.exe")


if($file.ProductVersion -gt "11.00.9600.17840") {
    echo "file is higher version"
}
elseif($file.ProductVersion -eq "11.00.9600.17840") {
    echo "file is equal version"
}
else {
    echo "file is lower version"
}

echo "Product version is:" $file.ProductVersion
```

FYI using ProductVersion instead of FileVersion because FileVersion seems to contain extra data sometimes.

It returns "file is a lower version" even though that's the same version that is displayed in Properties.

Do I need to do something else to get it to compare the ProductVersion property to a string?

Comment: All you've to do is casting your version string as version `if($file.ProductVersion -gt [version]"11.00.9600.17840") {`

Answer (score 6):

You don't compare that Property to a string. Create a [System.Version]-object from the string.

fixed code:

```
    $version = [System.Version]::Parse("11.00.9600.17840")
if($file.ProductVersion -gt $version) {
    echo "file is higher version"
}
elseif($file.ProductVersion -eq $version) {
    echo "file is equal version"
}
else {
    echo "file is lower version"
}
```

Comment: You can also use `ProductVersionRaw` which does this.

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell functions don't work like typical other language functions. You don't "return" a value. Instead, you output it to the Pipeline for display or further processing using Write-Output.  If you do it correctly, the output will be an actual System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo object from which you can compare versions.  See revised code below.

```
function Get-FileVersionInfo            
{   
  [CmdletBinding()]         
  param(            
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]            
    [string]$FileName)            

  if(!(test-path $filename)) {            
    Write-Error "File not found"
  }            

  Write-Output ([System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo]::GetVersionInfo($FileName))

}

$version = Get-FileVersionInfo -FileName "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe"
$version | Get-Member

$version.FileMajorPart
$version.FileMinorPart
$version.FileVersion
```