# Powershell Script Compare File Array Result Version to Be Removed Issues

Tags: arrays, powershell

Wrecking my logic circuits as I can't comprehend Powershell with some .NET thrown together for this compare file array results.  From the array results, script is then to compare each results file version against a set version and then to delete the file if is below/not equal to the set version.  I tried to use sample [Comparing file versions in Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46222706/comparing-file-versions-in-powershell) but it I cannot find the output issue as to why the behavior works on a Windows Server 2019 vs a Windows 10 Enterprise.  Deleting old profile Teams.exe data from the MS Teams Machine Wide crap.  Your assistance will be most appreciated!

My script deploys through MS Endpoint/SCCM

```
$TeamsPath = 'C:\Users*\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Teams\current\Teams.exe'

$FileVersion = @(Get-ChildItem -Path $TeamsPath -Recurse -Force)

foreach ($TeamsPath in $FileVersion){
    $ProductVersion = [System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo]::GetVersionInfo($TeamsPath).ProductVersion
    $TargetVersion = [System.Version]::Parse("1.3.0.13000")

    if ($ProductVersion -le $TargetVersion){
    Remove-Item -Path $TeamsPath.Directory -Force -Recurse
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problems with your code:

- (This may be posting artifact) You're looking to loop over all users' `AppData` folders, so the wildcard path must start with `'C:\Users\*\...` not `C:\Users*\...` - that is, `*` must be its own path component.
- There's no need to call `[System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo]::GetVersionInfo($TeamsPath)`, because the `.VersionInfo` [ETS](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/PowerShell-Docs/issues/6763) property that PowerShell decorates the `System.IO.FileInfo` instances with performs exactly that call behind the scenes.
- The `.ProductVersion` property contains a *string* representation of a version number; if you use it as the *LHS* of your `-le` comparison, *string comparison* is performed (the `[version]` (`System.Version`) RHS is then coerced to a string too).

The following is a streamlined version of your code with the problems corrected:

```bash
$teamsPath = 'C:\Users\*\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Teams\current\Teams.exe'
$targetVersion = [version] '1.3.0.13000'

Get-ChildItem -Path $teamsPath -Force | 
  ForEach-Object {
    if ([version] $_.VersionInfo.ProductVersion -le $targetVersion) {
      Remove-Item -LiteralPath $_.DirectoryName  -Force -Recurse -WhatIf
    }
  }
```

<sup>Note: The [`-WhatIf` common parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters#whatif) in the command above *previews* the operation. Remove `-WhatIf`  once you're sure the operation will do what you want.</sup>

Comment: Uninstall command for Teams revised answer with the changes that @mklement0 helped on.
`$UpdateRun = Split-Path $_.DirectoryName`
`  Start-Process -FilePath "$UpdateRun\Update.exe" -ArgumentList "--uninstall /s" -PassThru -Wait -ErrorAction STOP`

Answer (score 1):

Revised with the original answer to have a proper and cleaner routine to delete/uninstall Teams from old user profiles

```
$TeamsPath = 'C:\Users\*\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Teams'

$TargetVersion = [version] '1.3.0.13000'

Get-ChildItem -Path $TeamsPath -Filter "Teams.exe" -Force -Recurse | 
  ForEach-Object {
  if ([version] $_.VersionInfo.ProductVersion -le $TargetVersion) {
  
  $UpdateRun = Split-Path $_.DirectoryName 
  
  Start-Process -FilePath "$UpdateRun\Update.exe" -ArgumentList "--uninstall /s" -PassThru -Wait -ErrorAction STOP
  
  #Remove-Item -LiteralPath $_.DirectoryName  -Force -Recurse -WhatIf
  }
}
```